# Visual Studio file templates

Tags: templates, typescript, visual-studio-2015

I've played with the [ASP.NET Core Template Pack extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=MadsKristensen.ASPNETCoreTemplatePack) project template and saw that they have somehow manipulated the ts files to have sub-files under them. Like so:

```
 + app.component.ts
 |--- app.component.html
 |--- app.component.css
```

I would like to create a template in an ASP.NET MVC 4 Project which will organize the files like the demo above.

During my research i found this MSDN article [How to: Create Multi-file Item Templates](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms247115.aspx). Do you create templates in this way?

Does something like this already exists and i just didn't found it already?